# Converting curl request to angular http post request

Tags: curl, angular7, typeform

How can I convert the following curl request into HTTP post request in angular 7?

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.typeform.com/oauth/token \
  --data-urlencode 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
  --data-urlencode 'code={temporary_authorization_code}' \
  --data-urlencode 'client_id={your_client_id}' \
  --data-urlencode 'client_secret={your_client_secret}' \
  --data-urlencode 'redirect_uri=https://results-example.herokuapp.com/callback'
```

I tried the approach below but it doesn't work

```
this.httpClient.post(environment.typeForm.base_url + 'token', JSON.stringify({
        'grant_type' : 'authorization_code',
        'code': `${authCode}`,
        'client_id':`${*******}`,
        'client_secret':`${*******}` ,
        'redirect_uri':`${*******}`,
    }));
```

The grant_type shoud be 'authroization_code' as specified int the typeform documentation.

This is the error I get

```
{"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":500,"statusText":"Internal Server Error","url":"https://api.typeform.com/oauth/token","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for https://api.typeform.com/oauth/token: 500 Internal Server Error","error":{"code":"internal_server_error","description":"Internal server error"}}
```

You can find the documentation of the API I'm trying to use [here](https://developer.typeform.com/get-started/applications/)

Comment: Hi can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: @sedders123 I've updated the question with what I've tried so far and the error i get

Answer (score 1):

You can build a payload by concatenating all of your params together.

```js
const body = `grant_type=${grant}&code=${code}&client_id=${clientId}&client_secret=${clientSecret}&redirect_uri=${redirectUrl}`;
this.httpClient.post(environment.typeForm.base_url + 'token', body);
```

You can also try using the FormData type to create a payload.

```js
const payload = new FormData(); 
payload.append('grant_type', grantType); 
payload.append('code', code);
payload.append('client_id', clientId;
payload.append('client_secret', clientSecret);
payload.append('redirect_uri', redirectUrl);

this.httpClient.post(environment.typeForm.base_url + 'token', payload);
```